# Marshalling Different Classes with Spring MVC and JIBX

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jibx, spring-oxm

We are trying to build some RESTful services with Spring MVC. We will be providing several representations: XML, HTML, & JSON. We would like to use JiBX as the OXM technology.

We are currently having difficulty figuring out how to wire up Spring with JiBX. If we want to wire up a single class, for example `Customer`, we simply define a `JibxMarshaller`, an XML `MarshallingView`, and add it too our `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`. This works great.

The problem is we aren't sure how to wire up marshalling of multiple classes, for example, `Customer` and `User`. Each `JibxMarshaller` can support only one class (unlike the Jaxb2Marshaller which can support many). We tried declaring a marshaller for each class, but the `MarshallingView` only support one marshaller. Declaring multiple `MarshallingView`s does not work (it appears only the first one works).

Your advice is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <util:list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <property name="marshaller" ref="userMarshaller"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <property name="marshaller" ref="customerMarshaller"/>
            </bean>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="userMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jibx.JibxMarshaller">
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.mycompany.User"/>
</bean>
<bean id="customerMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jibx.JibxMarshaller">
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.mycompany.Customer"/>
</bean>
```

---

*Update based on Ritesh's answer below:*

It turns out that I was thrown off by the `targetClass` property of the `JibxMarshaller`. I thought it meant the marshaller would only work for a single class, however, it appears to just uses the target class as a way of finding all related bindings. So, the solution is to use just a single marshaller, using an arbitrary target class from your set of classes you have bindings for. For example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <util:list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <property name="marshaller" ref="jibxMarshaller"/>
            </bean>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jibxMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jibx.JibxMarshaller">
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.mycompany.User"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JiBX binding compiler adds `JiBX_bindingList` field to class files. At run time, the 'targetClass' (any compiled class with `JiBX_bindingList` field) is used to build a BindingFactory. It is the `getMappedClasses()` of [IBindingFactory](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/api/index.html?org/jibx/runtime/IBindingFactory.html) which is used by `JibxMarshaller`
in [supports()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jibx/JibxMarshaller.html#supports%28java.lang.Class%29) method to check if marshaller can marshal a class.

Please also see [JiBX runtime usage](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/runtime.html).

Comment: I'm finally revisiting this after several weeks and upon further investigation, it appears you are correct. I think the misunderstanding on my part is the "targetClass
" property on the marshaller. To me, this property implies the marshaller will only work for the target class, which is not true.

Comment: I've appended my solution to the original question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have this exact same problem but giving a single jibx marshler with an arbitrary class has not solved my problem. Is there any thing else which i should do?

Comment: I haven't used it for some time and so not sure if anything got changed. If you have a decompiler, can you verify that the (jibx compiled) class that you selected has JiBX_bindingList field?